# How to set width based on content length using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make width of each item based on the content but what I have so far set the width all the way to available spaces. flex: 0 0 auto does not seem to do the trick. What am I doing wrong?

Goal is have a width based on the content size.

```
[Hello]
[Hello world]
```

Currently

```
[Hello                   ]
[Hello world             ]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v6cgLjbd/8/

```
<span class='box'>
  <span class='item'>Hello</span>
  <span class='item'>Hello World</span>
  <span class='item'>Hello lOOOOONG text</span>
</span>

.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  background-color: gray;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `align-items: flex-start` on flex-container. When you use `flex-direction: column` on parent element, with `flex` property on child elements you control height not width.

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.item {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<span class='box'>
  <span class='item'>Hello</span>
  <span class='item'>Hello World</span>
  <span class='item'>Hello lOOOOONG text</span>
</span>
```